# Weird rhythmic static when realtime audio streaming MediaStreamAPI

Tags: javascript, audio, socket.io, getusermedia, mediastream

I have a small issue, This code below live streams audio from one client to another in the same room. This works by the first client sending audio data to the server which sends it to a separate client. When a different client receives the incoming audioData, the arraybuffer is changed to a float32array and then into an audio buffer that is then connected to an output device and played. The result of this is a realtime audio feed from one client to another. However, there is a static/click that seems to happen when one audiobuffer stops playing and the next one starts. However, when I increase the sample rate of the "audioC" audioContext, this static appears more frequently.
Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix this?

```js
const socket = io();
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioCtx = new AudioContext({
  latencyHint: 'interactive',
  sampleRate: 16384,
});
const audioC = new AudioContext()

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      console.log('getUserMedia supported.')

      navigator.getUserMedia(
        { audio: true },
        stream => {
          const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
          const processor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(16384, 1, 1)

          source.connect(processor)
          processor.connect(audioCtx.destination)
          processor.onaudioprocess = e => {
              socket.emit('Voice', e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0))
          }

          socket.on('Voice', msg => {
            var z = new Float32Array(msg, 0, 16384);
            console.log(z)
            const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer({
              length: 16384,
              sampleRate: 16384 
            });
            audioBuffer.copyToChannel(z, 0, 0);
            const source = audioC.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = audioBuffer;
            source.connect(audioC.destination);
            source.start();
          })
          audioCtx.resume()
        },
        err => console.error(err)
      )
    }
```

The server side just sends data to another client upon receiving the data.

Comment: `16384` isn't a common sample rate. Try `16000`, `22050`,  `44100`, or `48000`. The available sample rates are determined by the analog-to-digital stuff in your computer's sound chip. (`44100` was the sample rate on music -- Red Book -- CDs.) Better yet, get your stuff working without specifying the sample rate to your originating `AudioContext`. Just take the default. And maybe try a UInt16Array?

Comment: This worked great! I don't know why I didn't try that from the start lol

Comment: Hi. If you have time please write an answer to your own question saying what you did, for the benefit of the next person with a question like this.  Thanks!